# Nesting a form within a form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Here is a working answer. Instead of nesting a form within a form, I created a second form and positioned where I want to run it. It's tedious but it does what I want to do.

I need the separate query to open in a separate window.

I could use a second submit button with a different value in php. But I cannot force that query into opening in a second window, without losing the first window.

It's a taxi dispatch interface. Don't want to lose the hard-earned, typed data on the first page. The query into the second page is necessary to verify information collected in the first window. Possibly, we might run a query in a second window to verify and find an address and then use a handler to insert the found address back in the first window.

The second window is necessary. I only want to do a query on a couple items, in a second window.

I could use cookies and launch the query in a new window using a link. That might be more trouble than it is worth.

Anyone see another way to do it? I'm decent at PHP, just learning about jquery, but know nothing about ajax?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr"><head>
<title>test / crtp</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    position_mdiv()();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        position_mdiv();
    });
})

function position_mdiv(){

    var pos = $('#place_here').position();
    var width = $('#place_here').outerWidth();

    $('#div_2').css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: pos.top +2 + "px",
    left: (pos.left -300 + width) + "px"
});

}

</script>
<body>

<form id="CTRP_Form">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="div_1">
                    <input id="fnam" name="fnam" form="CTRP_Form" type="text">                
                    <input type=submit>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="place_here" style="background:yellow;width:300px;padding:0px;border:solid 2px #CCC">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>


<div id="div_2">
    <form id="query_Form">
        <input id="MyQuery" name="MyQuery" form="query_Form" type="text">
        <input type=submit>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered using an Iframe for the second form?

Comment: I thought about that. Did not try. I gave up on this above, and am attempting to pass data using cookies. Less complicated.